# HttpPost Json object property naming behavior

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, http-post

For HttpPost function

```
public async Task<Result> PostAsync([FromBody]Request request, [FromHeader(Name = "Cs-Auth")] string authKey=null)
    {
        try{
            HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(_config.ApiUrl, request);
                          
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            string responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


            Result result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Result>(responseText);

            return ProcessResult(result);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }
```

The Request class:

```
    public class Request
    {
        [JsonPropertyName("text")]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("user_id")]
        public string user_id { get; set; }

        [JsonPropertyName("rule_id")]
        public string PolicyId { get; set; }

        public Policy Policy {get; set;}
    }
```

The Json body:

```
    {
      "text": "sample",
      "user_id": "3455643",
      ...
    }
```

But the request I got in PostAsync looks like

[image]

I was expecting "text", not "Text".

I donot want to change property name "Text" in Request Class to "text", what do I need to do to define serialization/deserialization behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is working properly, your debugger just show data BEFORE changing. try this in your debugger

```
var jsonRequest= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);

    var content = new StringContent(jsonRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

 var response = await client.PostAsync(_config.ApiUrl, content);
```

jsonRequest

```
{
      "text": "sample",
      "user_id": "3455643",
      ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think the root cause is PostAsJsonAsync(). It will convert object to Json but uses JsonSerializerDefaults.Web so it may not behave as I wish.

Comment: @Daolin Yes, you are right.  I usually don't use PostAsJsonAsync . I prefer to serialize explicitly before sending.